# LINQ: Having trouble navigating across multiple jeft join

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, entity-framework, linq

What I'm trying to do in SQL looks like this:

```
SELECT
    ....
    ct.FirstName + ' ' + ct.LastName
    ....
FROM
    Leads l
    LEFT JOIN LeadContacts lc ON lc.LeadID = l.LeadID 
    LEFT JOIN Contacts ct on ct.ContactID = lc.ContactID
```

In the Lead model:

```
public class Lead
{
    ....
    public virtual ICollection<LeadContact> LeadContacts { get; set; }
    ....
}
```

And in the LeadContact model:

```
public class LeadContact
{
    ....
    [ForeignKey(nameof(LeadID))]
    public virtual Lead Lead { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(ContactID))]
    public virtual Contact Contact { get; set; }
    ....
}
```

And now, I'm trying to build an object from an instance of:

```
leads = IQueryable<Lead>...
```

And for the life of me, I can't figure out how to navigate to the Contacts table.

```
var results = leads.Select(l => new QuoteSearchItem
{
    ....
    SomeProperty = l.SomeProperty,
    LeadSales = l.LeadContacts. ?????
    SomeOtherProperty = l.SomeOtherProperty
    ....
 });
```

QuoteSearchItem.LeadSales is a string.  It needs to be:

```
Contacts.FirstName + " " + Contacts.LastName
```

Because of the relationship type, l.LeadContacts.Contacts is not an option.

What do I need to do so that this is possible?

Comment: Are there really more fields in LeadContact than just Lead and Contact?  If there isn't, EF will simplify your access and you can create `public virtual  ICollection<Contact> Contacts {get;set;}` directly in your `Lead` class (and also `public virtual ICollection<Lead> Leads {get;set;}` in your `Contact` class).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that easily if you use comprehension syntax (which use SelectMany when there are multiple froms):

```
var query = from l in Leads
            from lc in l.LeadContacts.DefaultIfEmpty()
            from ct in lc.Contacts.DefaultIfEmpty()
            select new
            {
               //....
               ContactName = ct.FirstName + ' ' + ct.LastName
               //....
            };
```

And if you wish, running this in LinqPad, you can get the lambda version + if that is Linq To SQL the SQL itself.

EDIT: Your class is implying that there is a single Contact per LeadContact, then you can shorten this:

```
var query = from l in Leads
            from lc in l.LeadContacts.DefaultIfEmpty()
            select new
            {
                //....
                ContactName = lc.Contact.FirstName + ' ' + lc.Contact.LastName
                //....
            };
```

It almost maps to this sample which use the Northwind sample database:

```
var data = from c in Customers
               from o in c.Orders.DefaultIfEmpty()
               select new {
                 CustomerId = c.CustomerID,
                 OrderId = (int?)o.OrderID,
                 Employee = o.Employee.FirstName + ' ' + o.Employee.LastName
               };
```

which yields this SQL:

```
-- Region Parameters
DECLARE @p0 NChar(1) = ' '
-- EndRegion
SELECT [t0].[CustomerID] AS [CustomerId], [t1].[OrderID] AS [OrderId], ([t2].[FirstName] + @p0) + [t2].[LastName] AS [Employee]
FROM [Customers] AS [t0]
LEFT OUTER JOIN [Orders] AS [t1] ON [t1].[CustomerID] = [t0].[CustomerID]
LEFT OUTER JOIN [Employees] AS [t2] ON [t2].[EmployeeID] = [t1].[EmployeeID]
```

EDIT: What I was saying, instead of:

```
var results = leads.Select(l => new QuoteSearchItem
{
    ....
    LeadSales = l.LeadContacts. ?????
    ....
});
```

Do it like:

```
var results = from l in leads 
              from lc in l.LeadContacts.DefaultIfEmpty() 
              select new  QuoteSearchItem
              {
                ....
                LeadSales = lc.Contact.FirstName + " " + lc.Contact.LastName
               ....
              };
```

Either in (method) lambda form or comprehension syntax, end result is same. When selectMany is needed I find comprehension syntax to be easier. And as I said, if you are dying for method syntax, try running it in LinqPad and it will give you lambda counterpart, something like:

```
var result = leads
   .SelectMany (
      l => l.LeadContacts.DefaultIfEmpty (), 
      (l, lc) => 
         new QuoteSearchItem
         {
            //... 
            LeadSales = lc.Contact.FirstName + " " + lc.Contact.LastName
         }
   );
```

Comment: Ok Cetin. THANK YOU!  So, can you help me out a little more?  How would I do this inside of my existing leads.select(...) statement?  See the OP.

Comment: I tried to write here, but got ugly because of formatting. Editing my answer instead.

Comment: Question:  Will your example right under "Do it like" honor the LEFT JOIN?

Comment: Yes it does honor a left join (DefaultIfEmpty() provides that). Check the SQL generated for Norhwind sample. --- oops missing DefaultIfEmpty() missing there, correcting.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like:

`l.LeadContacts.SelectMany(x => x.Contacts)`

But, your `Contact` property is not a list inside your `LeadContact` class. So either make it a list or you could access it like:

```
l.LeadContacts.Select(x => x.Contact)
```

Comment: Ok ok.... I'm starting to see the picture.  I can't edit the Contact property in the LeadContact class.  It's used too many other places.

Comment: No need to edit the LeadContact class. Understand that the relationship is Many to One, Many being the LeadLocations and One being the Contact. That is why you don't have a collection of Contacts. l.LeadContacts.Select(x => x.Contact) should get you what you want, as indicated by @Jinish.

Comment: Ok, and how would I handle making sure I only get the LeadContacts WHERE LeadId is equal to the LeadId of the records in 'lead'?  Or in other words: LEFT JOIN LeadContacts lc ON lc.LeadID = l.LeadID

Comment: And, how would I get Contact.FirstName + ' ' Contact.LastName?

Comment: var contact = l.LeadContacts.Select(x => x.Contact) as Contact; And then you could access the properties on your contact object

Comment: Thanks Jinish.  But, you may recall that I'm already doing this inside of a select(...)

Comment: something like: leads.SelectMany(x => x.LeadContacts).Select(x => x.Contact).Select(x => new { DisplayName = x.FirstName + "" + x.LastName }); if you could tell exactly what result you are trying to fetch, may be i could rough out a query??

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you need a Foreign Key in your **LeadContact** table. I will assume your Lead table has a LeadId field:

```
//Foreign key for Standard
public int LeadId { get; set; }

[ForeignKey("LeadId")]
public Lead Lead { get; set; }
```

That represents the relationship between Lead and Lead Contact and it will limit the records to the ones you want. LeadContact is a cross reference so I am sure it already has a "LeadId" field (or some other name) that maps to the Lead Id field in the Lead table so indicate that relationship as shown above.

Assuming LeadSales is of type `IEnumerable<string>`, you can then do:

```
var results = leads.Select(l => new QuoteSearchItem
{
    ....
    LeadSales = l.LeadContacts.Select(lc => lc.Contact.FirstName + " " + lc.Contact.LastName);
    ....
});
```

Comment: Ok, yes you are right.  There is a LeadId in the LeadContact table and that foreign key is already in the model. I edited the OP to reflect.

Comment: That's it then. When you do l.LeadContacts, you will only get the lead contact records that satisfy the relationship. When you do Select on that, you get the Contact for each of those LeadContact records, as indicated in the answer. Is there anything else you are looking for?

Comment: I see what you are looking to get now. I don't know the structure of QuoteSearchItem, but it looks like LeadSales should be an IEnumerable<string> type. You can then do: LeadSales = l.LeadContacts.Select(lc => lc.Contact.FirstName + " " + lc.Contact.LastName). I edited the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using contexts ?

```
var result = await context.SearchLead.AsNoTracking()
.Where(l => l.LeadContacts.Any(lc => lc.Contact == QuoteSearchItem))
.ToListAsync();
```

Comment: ok... the answer is "No" but I would like to get there.  I'd love to circle back to making this Async.  But first, I just need to get this working as-is.

Comment: Right, okay my bad. Check out this post on Microsoft, you’ll just have to make a few tweakers. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397895.aspx. Off topic but you should defiantly checkout entity framework when you get a chance. Tons of databases query options made easy.